# Imperativo singular de “ir” en dialectos con voseo

Tags: conjugación, voseo

Con este asunto de que la RAE aprobó el *iros* como imperativo plural pronominal de *ir* me quedé pensando que, al menos en dialecto rioplatense, al [trío de raíces](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supletismo) que forman el paradigma verbal de *ir* le hemos añadido una cuarta, sólo para el imperativo singular. No decimos *ve* / *vete* sino *andá* / *andáte*.

Mi pregunta principal: **¿es esto así en otras áreas voseantes?** Y secundariamente a eso: ¿hay algún otro dialecto que añada raíces supletivas de esta manera al paradigma de *ir* o de *ser* (el otro gran irregular)?

Comment: ¿Es realmente _andá_ el imperativo de "ir" en español rioplatense? A mí me suena más a que en estos casos prefieren el verbo "andar" al verbo "ir"?

Comment: @Rodrigo Funcionalmente es lo mismo. No hay otra manera de decirle a alguien que se vaya, usando un imperativo, con el paradigma estándar de *ir*, en nuestro dialecto. Una vez un compañero de facultad le dijo a otro frente a un grupo *Ite* (lo que sería un imperativo regular dentro de las normas voseantes) y 20 años después todavía recuerdo cómo nos reímos.

Comment: @Rodrigo Evidencia: sin dudar cualquier voseante argentino dirá que el equivalente de *andá para allá* en plural es *vayan para allá*.

Comment: Nota que ahora el imperativo voseante con un solo pronombre clítico en la mayoría de los casos ya no lleva tilde, a pesar de que sí los lleva sin ellos: *andá* pero *andate* (este cambio os afectó mucho más que la gente de otros dialectos)

Comment: He encontrado un escrito interesante sobre este tema: [El_voseo_y_el_modo_imperativ](https://www.academia.edu/2317042/El_voseo_y_el_modo_imperativo_Breves_apuntes_sobre_el_verbo_ir)

Comment: @blonfu Es muy bueno ese paper. Más allá de haber aceptado la respuesta de DGaleano, sería interesante incorporar algo de allí a una nueva respuesta.

Comment: Incluso en acentos no voseantes: @Rodrigo, ¿acaso como chileno no usas _anda/ándate_? Se puede decir que en Chile el verbo _ir_ o no tiene imperativo, o es _anda_. El DLE valida [_andá_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy) como imperativo de ir.

Comment: @Rafael Por supuesto, jamás uso "iré" o "vete". Mi duda es acerca de si (1) el verbo _andar_ se prefiere al verbo _ir_ o (2) _andá_ es una forma conjugada de l verbo _ir_. Es diferente: (1) es meramente un asunto de vocabulario, mientras que (2) es sintáctico, o sea que habría un cambio a nivel de sistema.

Comment: No entiendo como se podría decir que **andá** es una forma conjugada del verbo ir. Que usais andá para ve, vale. Pero que sea una forma conjugada de ir, no entiendo. Una cosa es el sentido, otra la etimología...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No pertenezco a ningún país o región voseante y mi respuesta se basa en el artículo [El voseo y el modo imperativo: Breves apuntes sobre el verbo ir](http://www.academia.edu/2317042/El_voseo_y_el_modo_imperativo_Breves_apuntes_sobre_el_verbo_ir) de Jose Roberto Alexander Quintanilla que parece ser un trabajo universitario.

Por una parte si vamos a la conjugación del verbo ir en el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy) nos dice que el imperativo para vos es *andá* aunque según dice el citado artículo el propio *«Diccionario de la Real Academia Española, en su edición de 2001, sugiere que “la forma propia del imper. sing. se suple con la correspondiente de andar”»*.

También se hace referencia al DPD que señala que el voseo no tiene una forma imperativa del verbo ir y se sustituye con el verbo andar: *andá* o *andate*:

> El imperativo de *ir* carece de forma propia de voseo y en su lugar se
>   usa el imperativo de *andar*, *andá* o *andate* (vos): *«Andá a buscar
>   la  máquina»* (Rovner Foto [Arg. 1977]); *«Andate y dejanos solos.
>   Estoy hablando con tu hermana»* (Viñas Maniobras [Arg. 1985]).

El artículo señala que siguiendo la regla general de como se construyen el resto de imperativos con el voseo, para el verbo *ir* tendríamos un extraño *í*:

> La regla general que todos los verbos usan para el imperativo con el
>   voseo consiste en sustraer la *r* final del infinitivo y acentuar la
>   última sílaba (*hablar = hablá, poner = poné, salir = salí*). La regla
>   es análoga a vosotros, en donde las terminaciones van además con *d
>   *(*hablad, poned,  salid*). Con esta regla, el imperativo de *ir*  con *vosotros* es *id*  y el de *vos*  sería entonces *í*, pero ¿se puede decir *i*?

Aunque marginalmente, parece que la forma *i* se usa en el habla coloquial en ciertas regiones:

> Preguntando a algunos informantes de los tres países voseantes de
>   Sudamérica, varios manifestaron que desconocen la forma *i* y que
>   siempre utilizarían *andá*. Sin embargo, más de alguno comentó que sí
>   ha escuchado *i*  en el habla coloquial, sobre todo en algunas partes
>   de Argentina (como Salta, Jujuy, Tucumán y Catamarca) pero que cada
>   vez se oye menos.

Siempre según el artículo, en El Salvador se escucharía la forma *i* habitualmente:

> No obstante el aparente poco uso de  *i* en Suramérica, en El Salvador
>   sí se oyen i, ite, ime, ile, etc.

Para más información y bibliografía visitar el [artículo](http://www.academia.edu/2317042/El_voseo_y_el_modo_imperativo_Breves_apuntes_sobre_el_verbo_ir), es bastante corto y creo que interesante aunque personas de paises voseantes podrán confirmar o refutar lo que en él se dice con mayor conocimiento de causa.

Answer (score 6):

En el caso de la región central cafetera de Colombia (Antioquia, Caldas, Risaralda, Quindío) y regiones aledañas donde se usa el voseo, si es así.

*Ve y vete* se usan en las novelas de la televisión pero en el uso normal siempre usamos *andá y andate*

> **Andá** traeme un tintico. (Ve tráeme una tasa pequeña de café)
>
> Dejá de joder y **andate** a recoger café (Deja de molestar y vete a cosechar café)

Respecto al plural de *andá para allá* hay dos opciones igualmente válidas e igulamente comunes

> Vayan pa'llá (Vayan para allá)
>
> Anden pa'llá (Anden para allá)

El resto del país no usa regularmente el voseo.

Comment: Lo mismo usamos  en Argentina (y lo digo con cierta vergüenza, porque me parece horrible).

Comment: @leonbloy Cada región tiene sus formas de hablar. A mi me parece en cambio muy interesante nuestro caso (centro de Colombia y Argentina) en el que hablamos con acentos tan diferentes que nadie creería que usamos las misma palabras y estructuras. Siendo dos regiones tan lejanas no tengo ni idea como convergimos a las misma forma de voseo.

Answer (score 1):

Soy de la Ciudad de Buenos Aires, bien porteño.

Soy profesor de inglés en la universidad, me fascina la etimología y he enseñado mi lengua nativa a extranjeros que visitaban la ciudad.

El método más sencillo que encontré para enseñar el "VOSEO RIOPLATENSE" es el de la siguiente fórmula;

Tomen la forma de vosotros de la variante española:

- cantar: cantad
- comer: comed
- salir: salid

Imaginar que la persona quiere conservar la pronunciación, pero sin escribir la -d: es decir, añadir acento a la vocal y luego quitar la -d:

- cantar: cantad: cantá
- comer: comed: comé
- salir: salid; salí

Esta fórmula necesita aclarar que ir tiene el irregular "andá", utilizando la base del verbo andar para su imperativo.

La realidad no es tan simple como decir que uno es correcto y el otro erróneo. La realidad es más compleja. La realidad es que "id" daría "í" siguiendo la lógica mencionada de la -d siendo eliminada.

La forma "ite" es perfectamente explicable oyendo "andate" y pensando en "ir", la forma "ite" sale incluso naturalmente, por regularización.